# Extracting comments from a .docx - can I include the text it is attached to?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How is the relationship between a Microsoft .docx comment and the (thereafter highlighted) text it relates to held in the xml or other metadata?  I am trying to programmatically extract comments and related data from a linked set of .docx (looping thru a single dir at present) and want also to include the 'highlighted' text the comment is attached to.  Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.  VBA would be superb.

Answer (score 0):

See [this sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413542%28v=office.12%29.aspx).  Although it is written in C#, it uses the Open XML SDK, which you can access from VB.NET.

Oh, I see you say VBA.  You want to do it as a Word macro?  How about [this](http://www.thedoctools.com/index.php?show=mt_comments_extract)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
Sub ExtractComments()
    Dim d As Document: Set d = ActiveDocument
    Dim c As Comment

    For Each c In d.Comments
        Debug.Print "Comment by " & c.Author
        Debug.Print vbTab & "Comment: " & c.Range.Text
        Debug.Print vbTab & "Regarding: " & c.Scope.Text & vbCrLf
    Next
End Sub
```